# t-sql for loop to iterate through tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-loop

I'm trying to execute the same sequence of actions on a list of tables, which are selected using a `where` clause.

```
Select table_name 
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
Where column_name = 'fieldA';
```

This generates a list of table names - these are the tables I want to handle with a for loop. Is there a way to iterate through this list of tables, something like this?

```
for i in @tablelist:

    alter table i add new_col varchar(8);
    update i set new_col = old_col;
```

Comment: Hmm... dunno if you can run DDL in a DML query... in fact, I'm pretty sure you can't.

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql

Comment: Why are you adding a new column and setting the value to be the same as another column? This seems kind of silly to have two columns with the same data in them. Perhaps you then are going to drop the old column? Maybe simply renaming these columns would be an option.

Comment: I'm doing other stuff to the new column, removing characters to change the formatting. Didn't think it relevant to the scope of the question.

Comment: Gotcha. If you are doing other stuff that makes total sense. As posted it seemed like simple renaming might have been a better path. Seems it isn't quite that simple. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
TableName VARCHAR(50),
Id int identity(1,1)
)


INSERT INTO @Table
Select table_name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
Where column_name = 'fieldA'

DECLARE @max int
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @id int = 1

select @max = MAX(Id) from @Table


WHILE (@id <= @max)
BEGIN

SELECT @TableName = TableName FROM @Table WHERE Id = @id
SET @SQL =     'alter table '+ @TableName +' add new_col varchar(8);
                update '+ @TableName + ' set new_col = old_col;'
PRINT(@SQL)  --COMMENT THIS LINE OUT AND COMMENT IN THE NEXT EXEC(@SQL) IF YOU SEE THE CORRECT OUTPUT
--EXEC(@SQL)
SET @id = @id +1
END
```

Answer (score 6):

You do not need to use loops for this. You can use the system view to generate your dynamic sql for you a lot simpler (and faster) than loops.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'alter table ['+ c.TABLE_NAME +'] add new_col varchar(8);
                update ['+ c.TABLE_NAME + '] set new_col = old_col;'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where c.COLUMN_NAME = 'fieldA'

select @SQL
--uncomment below when you are satisfied with the dynamic sql
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: In  the last step write EXEC(@SQL)

Comment: @BartoszSiemasz NO. using sp_executesql is a better choice. In this case it doesn't much matter but EXEC does not allow parameters where sp_executesql does. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql

Comment: Ok, sp_executesql delivers additional value for the future amendments, right.

Comment: I'm getting the error `The data types nvarchar(max) and varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.` The `old_col` and `fieldA` fields are always varchar(10) in each table. Tried changing `declare @SQL varchar(max) = ''` but same error.

Comment: apologies, it's because I'm doing a string operation which I left out of the original question!

Comment: No apologies needed. I was looking for a simpler path to the end. :) Glad this works for you.

Comment: the `@SQL` looks like `alter table [fieldA]` where it should be parsing the name of a table

Comment: Thanks @joshi123. I of course can't test this. Obviously you need to change that to TABLE_NAME. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For looping you either have to use [cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql) or while exists construct, where you remove entry from temporary table each time you process it.

As for passing table name to query, there is no way to do that without creating dynamic SQL query. You do that by creating query in string with concatenating table name into the right place. Use `QUOTENAME` function to perform quoting of name if there are any spaces or weird characters.

Example with cursor:

```
DECLARE @tables TABLE (
    Name SYSNAME
);
DECLARE @tableName SYSNAME;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

INSERT INTO @tables
SELECT i.table_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS i
WHERE i.column_name = 'fieldA';

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT Name
FROM @tables;

OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur
INTO @tableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' ADD new_col varchar(8);';
    SET @sql = @sql + N'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + N' SET new_col = old_col;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur
    INTO @tableName;    
END

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this action would be to feed your list of tables you want to alter into a SQL cursor and iterate through the cursor to execute the `ALTER` table command on each table. The documentation on how to create a SQL cursor can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Another way to accomplish this would be using a `while` loop in SQL with a count iterator. Information on this solution can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql